# Are Android XML style attributes not overridden in order?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` which should have `10dp` padding in the top and bottom, and `30dp` on the left. I then tried:

```
android:padding="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
```

That's what I'd do in CSS. But it doesn't work.

Regardless of the order, my left padding is `10dp`. Are Android style attributes not overridden in the order they appear? If so, is there any list of priorities? 
Ex: `android:padding always overrides android:paddingLeft`

Overriding is an important feature in CSS which saves a lot of coding, so I wanted to know if that's possible in Android.

Maybe I just couldn't find the answer with the right terms. If someone could point me where to understand it I'd be very appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can remember, `android:padding` applies to top, bottom, left and right and will override all other padding attributes - the order in the XML file isn't taken into consideration. If you want 10dp top and bottom then you need to forget `android:padding` and specify them separately. If you're concerned about repetitive XML coding, you can create a separate XML file and use merge or include or alternatively creat a 'style'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Android layout system is different from CSS. It does not care about the order of the properties, and `padding` always overrides `paddingLeft`, `paddingRight`, etc.

You can find the relevant source code in View.java [here (padding is set)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L3739) and [here (if padding is set it is used, even if paddingLeft is set)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L4111).

This is the most important snippet:

```
if (padding >= 0) {
    leftPadding = padding;
    topPadding = padding;
    rightPadding = padding;
    bottomPadding = padding;
    mUserPaddingLeftInitial = padding;
    mUserPaddingRightInitial = padding;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.2_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#line-2738),
when you set the padding attribute it can be overridden by other padding attributes.